# Help With Developer Menu In Web Browsers

Tags: performance, browser, safari, timeline

I mostly use safari for web browsing, and testing for web development, but I have noticed that on a few pages "Paint" is constantly being fired under the rendering timeline in the timeline pane under the debug menu. I was wondering if anyone could explain what that possibly could be or mean. I have tried searching the internet, but can not find any information on it. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you disable all the extensions?

Comment: with javascript disabled, something is "painted" about 4 times while the site is rendered. So, it something javascript. I could probably figure this out if there was some documentation on the Wekbkit developer menu, but i don't know exactly what "paint" means. I would assume a canvas element or svg or something but I am using nothing that i can think of that it would be, The only thing i can think i can think of is it some jQuery plugin. Ill have to go through the plugins im using and see if i can figure it out.

Comment: "paint" means something is rendering part of the page again, ie. redisplays that part.

Comment: if you want to shoot that up as an answer, ill give you credit, that is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due, to some plugins I am using. specifically jScrollPane, could be so high, due to other plugins.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior may be an indication of time-based execution of javascript, as done with setTimeout() or setInterval(). Most browsers will do repaint that's hard to predict even on small changes to the dom tree. If you have a URL for the page in question, we could sort out your browser issues from problems on the page itself.

Comment: well, i figured out through process of trial and error, that it was the jQuery plugin, jScrollPane. One of the options of the plugin is to set the scrollbars to autoReinitialize, which what was causing the constant repainting and was degrading performance. Its really unfortunate because i love the plugin, and there doesn't seem to be any other options.

Comment: which yeah, it was time based.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to HTML5 with canvas elements constantly being repainted.

Comment: I am not using any canvas elements to my knowledge, I am trying to fix this, I don't want it to affect performance, I was hoping the webkit documentation site would have a little better documentation on the developer menu, but there is practically nothing.

Comment: I am using jQuery and jQuery UI, but nothing that should be using canvas elements. unless the jQuery plugin jScrollPane uses canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the loaded page contains different elements (like images, flash,..); The browser requests each element separately. 'Paint' is constantly fired as soon as the requested element is received by the browser.

Comment: well, i am not saying you wrong, because i am not sure what the 'paint' element is in the developer menu. unfortunately, the documentation on the developer menu is almost non-existent, but I was using the jQuery plugin jScrollPane, which basically allows you to style the scrollbars of the page, or scrolling DIV, and I had the scrollbars set to autoReinitialize, bascially so if something changed in size, the scrollbars would adjust accordingly, because the way the plugin works is it calculates the size of the scrollbars when the page is loaded, and thats that for the bars, but if the page

Comment: changes size in anyway the bars will not adjust without that option on, so the bars were constantly being repainted, on a set timer. This is what was constantly being repainted, but once, i got rid of the plugin, this problem was also gone, it was heavily degrading performance, and now almost nothing is painted on the page, so i don't think 'paint' is constantly fired normally when an image is called, i cant say for flash, but for most elements, i dont think this is true. Paint almost never shows up now.